# Vaadin architectural questions - Single-Page App? Clean model-view-controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, vaadin

I have some simple questions regarding Vaadin architecture.

1. Vaadin doc claims it is a [Single-Page Application (SPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) but how can it be since pages are rendered on the server-side with some JavaScript here and there?
   If the answer is yes/maybe, how does Vaadin solve page routing on the client-side?
2. Does Vaadin offer clean model-view-controller separation? Is it easy to unit test controllers?

At the end, why would you choose Vaadin in 2017?

Comment: Asking about choosing Vaadin is too broad for Stack Overflow. But a quick synopsis of the motivation: Vaadin is designed for building user interfaces for web apps with the style & quality of native apps aimed at enterprise-style purposes such as accounting, inventory, workflow, etc. Ideal for developers who want to use the features of Java (reliability, performance, great tooling, rich libraries) server-side without knowing nitty-gritty details of HTTP, HTML, CSS, DOM, JavaScript, WebSocket, Push, and the other underlying web-standards technologies handled transparently client-side by Vaadin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Vaadin doc claims it is a SPA but how can it be since pages are rendered on the server-side with some javascript here and there? If the answer is yes/maybe, how does Vaadin solve page routing on the client-side?

*"pages are rendered..." is incorrect.*

The only page is rendered just in the beginning, after the first request, to be more precise. After that, its just DOM deltas that are fetched from server in JSON.
Vaadin does not claim to handle page routing, as there is only one page.

See the behavior for yourself in the [current Vaadin demonstration sites](https://vaadin.com/demo), and the older [Reindeer Theme demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme).

Comment: +Vikrant; I said Vaadin claims to be SPA but they don't mention if page routing is handled on the client side... Does it means that you can create a single page (lets say with a menu) and click on the menu items which in turn would result in a part of the page being refreshed with new content (ie. routing), not the whole page that gets fetched via the server? Sry for maybe asking stupid questions, Vaadin is a server-side technology so it confuses me maximally regarding its claim of being an SPA.

Comment: Vaadin does not know or understands page routing.

Comment: Does it means that you can create a single page (lets say with a menu) and click on the menu items which in turn would result in a part of the page being refreshed with new content (ie. routing), not the whole page that gets fetched via the server?   -  Exactly.

Comment: +Vikrant: thx for the answers. Btw, how is data exchanged between server and browser? REST w JSON? Ex. a textbox and a button is present in a form. When a user clicks on the button textbox value will be sent to the server as JSON or just string-value?

Comment: Data is fetched as JSON (transparently). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864543/vaadin-client-side-application-understanding/25869727#25869727